# High training accuracy but input is always classified to the same class in keras DNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using the Xception architecture and data augmentation on 3 classes. My original dataset has 3 images in each of the three classes, organized in a directory.

```
# import the necessary packages
from main.cnn.networks.lenet import LeNet
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2 as cv
import ssl

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    fill_mode='constant',
    cval=255.0,
    rotation_range=90,
    zoom_range=[1.0, 1.3],
    rescale=1.0/255.0
)
it = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_data/',
    target_size=(260, 380),
    batch_size=9,
    save_to_dir='augmented_data/',
    save_format='jpeg'
)

validation_ds = image_dataset_from_directory (
    directory='validation_data/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=1,
    image_size=(380, 260)) 

# scale data to the range of [0, 1]
def normalize(data, labels):
    return data / 255.0, labels 
validation_ds = validation_ds.map(normalize)

# initialize the optimize and model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
model = keras.applications.Xception(weights=None, input_shape=(380, 260, 3), classes=3)
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training...")
model.fit(it, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=100, verbose=1)

# show the accuracy on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating...")
(loss, accuracy) = model.evaluate(validation_ds, batch_size=3, verbose=1)
print("[INFO] accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy * 100))

for img, label in validation_ds:
    probs = model.predict(img)
    prediction = probs.argmax(axis=1)

    print("PREDICTION: " + str(probs))
    print("ACTUAL LABEL: " + str(label))
```

My training accuracy converges to 1.0000, but the call to model.predict looks like this:

```
[INFO] accuracy: 33.33%
PREDICTION: [[0.30813622 0.3550096  0.3368542 ]]
ACTUAL LABEL: tf.Tensor([[1. 0. 0.]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
PREDICTION: [[0.3081677  0.35502157 0.33681074]]
ACTUAL LABEL: tf.Tensor([[0. 1. 0.]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
PREDICTION: [[0.3081628  0.35502544 0.3368117 ]]
ACTUAL LABEL: tf.Tensor([[0. 1. 0.]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
PREDICTION: [[0.30813095 0.3550423  0.33682677]]
ACTUAL LABEL: tf.Tensor([[0. 0. 1.]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
...
```

For some reason, the second class is always chosen, which is why my model.evaluate accuracy is stuck at 33.3%. I've tried toggling the various batch sizes, learning rates, and other hyperparameters, but can't get this result to change.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your neural network simply hasn't trained enough. You have a batch size of 9, 1 step per epoch, and 100 epochs. This means that by the end of your training, only 900 samples will have passed through the network. I'm not sure at what point Keras shuffles, but this could even be 900 times the same images.

I suggest you increase `steps_per_epoch` by a lot, and probably increase batch size too.

Comment: At some point your image size is (260, 380), then (380, 260), is this normal?

Comment: Yes, that's due to the fact that target_size is (height, width) for some reason while the other instances are (width, height). Thanks for the advice, anyhow - I'll try it out.